# Gradle dependency cache maybe corrupt

Tags: android, android-studio

I have this error:

[image]

My network is fine, I tried every other answer. I even reinstalled Android Studio to older version and still nothing changes. When I click re-download dependencies nothing happens, it used to work properly when I used it about 7 months ago. Now I don't know what's gone wrong.

Here is my build.gradle:

[image]

Comment: "i tried every other answer" -- we have no way to know what those are, if you do not link to them. I would close Android Studio, delete (or move to a temporary location) the contents of `~/.gradle/caches/`, then try your project again.

Comment: Show your build.gradle.

Comment: @CommonsWare where should these files be?

Comment: @MilosLulic added it

Comment: On macOS and Linux, they are where I noted (`~/.gradle/caches/`). On Windows, `~` should map to some sort of user home directory (`C:\Users\...\`??? -- it's been a long time since I developed using Windows...)

Comment: @CommonsWare i found folder .gradle/caches containing versions of the gradle if its the one you meant and i did moved the files which were in it but it didn't have any effect.